# Paypal App is "Conditionally Approved".What is the timeline to get it approved?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created and submitted a Paypal application ( using the classic API). The application is in a conditionally approved state. Paypal reached out and asked additional questions which I responded back with details. The application does not use the Paypal API to make payments. It only reads transactions related data and shows useful reports and insights for users. The API permissions requested are

```
1.Obtain transaction specific information.
2.Obtain your paypal account balance
3.Search your transaction specific information.
4.Search your transactions for items that match specific criteria and display the results
```

I was able to get a live app id and also have the API username, password and API signature. However since our app uses Paypal oauth, the permissions part doesn't work . My guess is this is because the app is conditionally approved. Is this the right assumption? Also what is the typical timeline for an app to get approved? My Paypal account from which I created and submitted the app is a verified account. I have sent messages from within my developer portal to support but I haven't heard anything back.

So far we have been working with a sandbox account. The live application I created is in a different account than the sandbox account. I am not sure if this is an issue.Would be great if someone who has been through the process can confirm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/369450)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not really a "typical" time frame for app approvals as too many factors go into the approval process. The best thing would be to call in to PayPal to inquire on the status.